# scroll/move the page to the top after page postback from button click?

Tags: c#

I have a button which validates the username(Have this username textbox at the bottom of the page) on server side, and if username doesnot exist in the database it will return and give some error at the top of the page throgh a label. But inside button click I need to write the code if username doesnot exists scroll the page to the top.

How can I do this?

THanks

Comment: Just like you would "return and give some error" you can call a simple [javascript function](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-scroll-top/)

Answer (score 0):

After a post-back, the page typically scrolls to the top. If it does not, then this has to be done in javascript. You can use something like what Ilya posted: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-scroll-top/.